# results_as_hash возвращает массив с хэшами

Tags: ruby, sqlite3

```
    require 'rubygems'
require 'sqlite3'

input = File.open 'test.csv', 'r'

db = SQLite3::Database.new 'test.db'
db.results_as_hash = true

db.execute 'drop table if EXISTS users'

db.execute 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users
    (
        name            TEXT,
        email           TEXT,
        Bdate           TEXT,
        Registration    INTEGER,
        Status          TEXT
    )'

while (line = input.gets)
    arr = []
    line.strip!
    arr = line.split('; ')

    db.execute "insert into Users (name, email, Bdate, Registration, Status) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", [arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3], arr[4]]
    end 
end

input.close

result = db.execute 'select * from Users'
```

В результате puts result.inspect выдает

```
[{"name"=>"Иванов Иван", "email"=>"ivan@aaa.ru", "Bdate"=>"12.01.1974", "Registration"=>"12.12.2007 15:41", "Status"=>"On", 0=>"Иванов Иван", 1=>"ivan@aaa.ru", 2=>"12.01.1974", 3=>"12.12.2007 15:41", 4=>"On"}, {"name"=>"Петров Петр", "email"=>"petr@mailtest.ru", "Bdate"=>"01.03.1969", "Registration"=>"13.12.2007 20:41", "Status"=>"Off", 0=>"Петров Петр", 1=>"petr@mailtest.ru", 2=>"01.03.1969", 3=>"13.12.2007 20:41", 4=>"Off"}, {"name"=>"Сидоров Семен", "email"=>"sidr@test2.ru", "Bdate"=>"02.03.1989", "Registration"=>"14.12.2007 5:21", "Status"=>"Off", 0=>"Сидоров Семен", 1=>"sidr@test2.ru", 2=>"02.03.1989", 3=>"14.12.2007 5:21", 4=>"Off"}, {"name"=>"Пупкин Василий", "email"=>"pupkin@testtest.ru", "Bdate"=>"18.11.1988", "Registration"=>"15.12.2007 15:41", "Status"=>"On", 0=>"Пупкин Василий", 1=>"pupkin@testtest.ru", 2=>"18.11.1988", 3=>"15.12.2007 15:41", 4=>"On"}, {"name"=>"Кузнецов Александр", "email"=>"smith@smith.com", "Bdate"=>"04.03.1999", "Registration"=>"16.12.2007 3:28", "Status"=>"On", 0=>"Кузнецов Александр", 1=>"smith@smith.com", 2=>"04.03.1999", 3=>"16.12.2007 3:28", 4=>"On"}, {"name"=>"Пушкин Александр", "email"=>"pas@pas.ru", "Bdate"=>"06.06.1799", "Registration"=>"17.12.2007 15:41", "Status"=>"Off", 0=>"Пушкин Александр", 1=>"pas@pas.ru", 2=>"06.06.1799", 3=>"17.12.2007 15:41", 4=>"Off"}, {"name"=>"Лермонтов Михаил", "email"=>"lermontov@yyyy.ru", "Bdate"=>"03.10.1814", "Registration"=>"18.12.2007 15:41", "Status"=>"Off", 0=>"Лермонтов Михаил", 1=>"lermontov@yyyy.ru", 2=>"03.10.1814", 3=>"18.12.2007 15:41", 4=>"Off"}, {"name"=>"Гоголь Николай", "email"=>"gogol@gggg.ru", "Bdate"=>"19.03.1809", "Registration"=>"19.12.1999 15:41", "Status"=>"Off", 0=>"Гоголь Николай", 1=>"gogol@gggg.ru", 2=>"19.03.1809", 3=>"19.12.1999 15:41", 4=>"Off"}]
```

т.е. result предcтавляет из себя массив с хэшами, и значения в этих хэшах дублируются с ключами '0', '1', '2' и т.д.
Подскажите, что не так?

Comment: Ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27065389/ruby-sqlite3-results-as-hash-returns-duplicate-data

Comment: Что result будет хэшем и значения не будут повторяться

Comment: А с чего бы вдруг `db.execute` возвращать хэш? Какие ключи вы в нём ожидаете?

Comment: Ну db.results_as_hash = true заставляет же возвращать хэш внутри массива с ключами - названиями колонок в БД, вот этого и хочу, только не внутри массива, ну и без дублей.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Всё работает правильно.

Это просто приём, позволяющий обращаться к колонкам в каждой строчке не только по названию, но и по порядковому номеру.

Названия не очевидны, если речь идёт о выражениях, к примеру.
А порядковые номера неочевидны, если используется `*` в `SELECT`'е.

---

Абстрактно: база возвращает упорядоченный набор строк. **Всегда.** Без явных ключей (индексы в массивах не в счёт), т. к. их может не быть, поэтому для драйвера БД нет никакого смысла реализовывать возврат результата одним хэшмапом. Можете преобразовать в нужный вам самостоятельно.

Конкретно: в вашем случае, при `results_as_hash: true` "упорядоченный набор" это массив, а каждая строчка в нём это хэшмап, в котором ключи идентифицируют колонки (дважды, по имени и по номеру), а значения... значения.

> #### [`#results_as_hash`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/sqlite3/SQLite3%2FDatabase:results_as_hash)
>
> A boolean that indicates whether rows in result sets should be returned as hashes or not.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался. Я-то думал, что конструкция result.values.join("; ") позволит мне быстро вывести строку в нужном виде.